# Git push access denied from inside /etc

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I am trying make my puppet directory (/etc/puppet) a Git repo and push to GitHub from there. Everything works from from my home directory but from inside /etc/puppet, I get a Permission denied (publickey) error, even if I use sudo. It seems like maybe there is a problem reading my public key but my Linux experience is mediocre so I can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a `git` manipulations from `/etc` (I won't comment on whether or not that is a good idea) you will need to be doing it as root. I would do:

```
sudo su -
cd /etc
```

before you try your git commands. Now, when you try a `git push` it will be looking for your private key in the `.ssh` directory within the home directory for `root`, i.e. `~root/.ssh` which is normally `/root/.ssh`. You will want to create another public/private key pair for the root user, and add that to the permitted ssh keys for your github repository.